# Need to create an hourly weather update from API using this JSON doc and using $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I have to display an hourly forecast for the current day. 
something looking like:

9p - 78F
10p - 76F
etc...

This is what I have so far but if you look at the JSON the layout is strange and not letting me pull info out. I need hour and temperature to display.

```
$.ajax({
                url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/56763c83b2ae28c3/forecast/q/TX/Dallas.json",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data){
                    var hourly_forecast = data['hourly_forecast','','FCTTIME'];
                    var hour1 = hourly_forecast['hour'];
                    $('.hour1').html(hour1);
                }
            });
```

JSON data (copied from site)

```
{
response: {
version: "0.1",
termsofService: "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
features: {
hourly: 1
}
},
hourly_forecast: [
{
FCTTIME: {
hour: "15",
hour_padded: "15",
min: "00",
min_unpadded: "0",
sec: "0",
year: "2015",
mon: "12",
mon_padded: "12",
mon_abbrev: "Dec",
mday: "11",
mday_padded: "11",
yday: "344",
isdst: "0",
epoch: "1449867600",
pretty: "3:00 PM CST on December 11, 2015",
civil: "3:00 PM",
month_name: "December",
month_name_abbrev: "Dec",
weekday_name: "Friday",
weekday_name_night: "Friday Night",
weekday_name_abbrev: "Fri",
weekday_name_unlang: "Friday",
weekday_name_night_unlang: "Friday Night",
ampm: "PM",
tz: "",
age: "",
UTCDATE: ""
},
temp: {
english: "75",
metric: "24"
},
dewpoint: {
english: "61",
metric: "16"
},
condition: "Partly Cloudy",
icon: "partlycloudy",
icon_url: "http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
fctcode: "2",
sky: "47",
wspd: {
english: "16",
metric: "26"
},
wdir: {
dir: "S",
degrees: "176"
},
wx: "Partly Cloudy",
uvi: "1",
humidity: "62",
windchill: {
english: "-9999",
metric: "-9999"
},
heatindex: {
english: "-9999",
metric: "-9999"
},
feelslike: {
english: "75",
metric: "24"
},
qpf: {
english: "0.0",
metric: "0"
},
snow: {
english: "0.0",
metric: "0"
},
pop: "0",
mslp: {
english: "29.72",
metric: "1006"
}
},
```

Comment: try changing var hourly_forecast = data['hourly_forecast','','FCTTIME']; to var hourly_forecast = data['hourly_forecast'][0]['FCTTIME'];

Comment: Tried this:$.ajax({
                url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/56763c83b2ae28c3/forecast/q/TX/Dallas.json",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data){
                    var hourly_forecast = data['hourly_forecast'][0]['FCTTIME'];
                    var hour1 = hourly_forecast[0]['hour'];
                    $('.hour1').html(hour1);
                }
            });
Didn't work.

Comment: it seems you have changed `var hour1 = hourly_forecast['hour'];` line to `var hour1 = hourly_forecast[0]['hour'];` also, change only previous line as in my comment. Any way see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**According to the `json` response you have given,**

Change

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/56763c83b2ae28c3/forecast/q/TX/Dallas.json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    var hourly_forecast = data['hourly_forecast', '', 'FCTTIME'];
    var hour1 = hourly_forecast['hour'];
    $('.hour1').html(hour1);
  }
});
```

To

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/56763c83b2ae28c3/forecast/q/TX/Dallas.json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    var hourly_forecast = data['hourly_forecast'][0]['FCTTIME'];
    var hour1 = hourly_forecast['hour'];
    $('.hour1').html(hour1);
  }
});
```